# Cocos2d-x: CCMoveTo not smooth after using many times

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

currently, I'm using touch end to move a sprite (also scale while moving)

```
void Sample::move(CCSprite* sprite){
    moveTo = CCMoveTo::create(0.5f,ccp(0, 3));
        scale = CCScaleTo::create(0.5f, 0.0f);
        sprite->runAction(CCSpawn::create(scale, moveTo, NULL));
}
```

after about 20 times call this function, the move action become not smooth.

Anyone can help me, why it become not smooth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird things happen when you call actions and actions were already running (jumpy movements are common). Try calling `stopAllActions()` before `runAction()`.